# Center image around user clicked position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move an image so that it is centered around the position that the user clicked, both vertically and horizontally, using JavaScript. How would this be accomplished?

I have tried the following code, but it aligns the top left corner of the image to the position that was clicked, which is not what I want.

```js
document.onclick = userClicked;
function userClicked() {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var cat = document.getElementById("catAppear");
  cat.style.display = '';
  cat.style.position = 'absolute';
  cat.style.left = x + 'px';
  cat.style.top = y + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img alt="catAppear" id="catAppear" style="display: none" src="https://www.coopmcs.com/dotclear/public/chat.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: This question is ambiguous. Are you trying to make the image appear with the top-left corner positioned at the centre of your cursor (sounds like what you're asking)? Or you would like your image centered on the position clicked by the cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the width and height of the image and divide them by two, then subtract the x by the width divided by two and subtract the y by the height divided by two. This'll give you the center of the image.

```js
document.onclick = userClicked;
function userClicked() {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var cat = document.getElementById("catAppear");
  cat.style.display = "block";
  cat.style.left = x - (cat.width/2) + 'px';
  cat.style.top = y - (cat.height/2) + 'px';
};
```

```css
#catAppear {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img alt="catAppear" id="catAppear" style="display: none" src="https://www.coopmcs.com/dotclear/public/chat.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply subtract half the image's width from the x-coordinate and half the height from the y-coordinate to center the image around the clicked position.

```js
document.onclick = userClicked;
function userClicked() {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var cat = document.getElementById("catAppear");
  cat.style.display = '';
  cat.style.position = 'absolute';
  cat.style.left = x - cat.width / 2 + 'px';
  cat.style.top = y - cat.height / 2 + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img alt="catAppear" id="catAppear" style="display: none" src="https://www.coopmcs.com/dotclear/public/chat.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @pual No problem.